# Java openStream method character limit?

Tags: java, file, url, limit

This is the code I tried.

```
Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get("NewFile.txt"));
URL smallURL = new URL(url);

Files.copy(smallURL.openStream(), Paths.get("NewFile.txt"));
System.out.println(Files.size(Paths.get("NewFile.txt")));
```

It works fine if I have a url with less than a certain number of characters, but when I try it with a url link with 150,000 characters it only copies over about 65,000 characters into the "NewFile.txt".

Is there a cap to how many characters you can feed .openStream? How can I get around this?

Edit: I looked at the exact characters where it stops adding to the file and I could not notice anything unique about them. The pattern at the point had almost certainly already occurred and no error happened.

Comment: Did you close the InputStream at the end ?

Comment: I did not. I am also not sure how when I don't have an input stream object.

Comment: Look at my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59414975/9710708

Comment: I just thought of something could it be the result of the website rate limiting me or something of that nature?

Comment: I don't think so, can i get the url ?

Comment: https://api.jikan.moe/v3/user/Scale_of_1_to_10/animelist/completed

Comment: Very strange. It works for me (124245 characters in NewFile.txt).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204612/discussion-between-william-and-void).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such limitation on InputStream. ( as the name says its a streaming API, it reads data in a streaming fashion)

```
URL url = new URL("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft");
Files.copy(url.openStream(), Paths.get("NewFile.txt"));
System.out.println(Files.size(Paths.get("NewFile.txt")));
```

this prints - 547055

I suspect something could be odd with the content what you have in the URL you are using, cross check it.

Comment: If I do not ignore any exceptions thrown I get a Premature EOF exception from my problem URL. Perhaps some part of that URL gives a false positive that the file is done. I am not sure how to identify the specific cause of this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the InputStream of the URLConnection :

```java
Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get("NewFile.txt"));
URL smallURL = new URL(url);
InputStream is = smallURL.openStream();
Files.copy(is, Paths.get("NewFile.txt"));
System.out.println(Files.size(Paths.get("NewFile.txt")));
is.close();
```

Comment: Okay, I tried that and I still only get half of the characters.